# Panels linking to articles or pages

Tags: drupal

New to Drupal. Installed it, set Bartik theme as default, created a few pages with a menu. Now I would like to do something like this:

[image]

where the pictures with descriptions link to either other pages or articles. Each of them should have custom size.
What is the simplest way to do it?

For the testing I have created 4 articles on my home page, but obviously they sit one on top of each other. The same happens when I add blocks.

Comment: Are you asking if a module exists to do this, or are you asking how to find the link addresses for pages so that you can add 6 pictures to a page and link to the associated pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not better option to this than to install and use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. You can achieve exactly what you want using the nice UI it provides.

> You need Views if
>
> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it differently.
>   You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type.
>   You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles the way you like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts for that month.

P.S - Views module is the most used and installed module in Drupal, hence, it will be a part of Drupal 8 core.